# Set Time Machine to backup once per day instead of once an hour

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

I use Time Machine to backup my Mac (running Mavericks 10.9.1). The backup process runs at the standard once per hour. This often slows down my machine while I'm trying to work on it. Understanding that it will provide less protection, is it possible to adjust Time Machine to backup at a different interval (e.g. once per day) instead of once per hour without installing third-party software?

Answer (score 7):

No.  Given that there are several third-party utilities that provide this functionality (and nothing else), like [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/), it seems highly unlikely that there's a built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

or like this http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html

works nice for me under Mavericks, ML and Lion

Comment: Hi welcome to AskDifferent, I find if a question is worth answering it is worth upvoting.  Also some instructions and a link may get you more upvotes. Please take the time to read the Answer and Question section of the [help](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) page.

Comment: I tried, but I am new and do not have the reputation for upvoting :-(

Answer (score 0):

for once a day I just do it manually, with the Time Machine turned off in the System preferences.